# Getting the login user GUID in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, membership-provider

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC 5 web application, and I am using forms authentication against our LDAP server.

Here is the login action method:-

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    MembershipProvider domainProvider;
    domainProvider = Membership.Providers["ADMembershipProvider"];
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
```

And the related entities inside our `web.config` file, which connects to the LDAP:

```
<providers>
<add name="ADMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, &#xA;   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="TestDomain1ConnectionString" connectionUsername="ad.user" connectionPassword="***" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName"/>
</providers>

<connectionStrings>
<add name="TestDomain1ConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://ad-Tgroup.intra/OU=T,DC=ad-Tgroup,DC=intra"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Currently I am storing the `domainname\username` inside our log table, as follows:

```
string ADusername = User.Identity.Name.ToString();
repository.InsertOrUpdateResturant(resturant, ADusername);
```

Using the `User.Identity.Name` might work in almost 95% of the cases because it can uniquely identify any user, but on the other hand, the username might be changed (let's say a user got married or divorced). So I am planning on replacing my `User.Identity.Name` and getting the user GUID instead. But I'm not sure if MVC 5 provides a way to get the login user GUID. For example, I cannot write `User.Identity.GUID`.

Comment: Correct, you won't be able to access the GUID directly off the principal. However, while `User.Identity.Name` may not be unique enough as a persistent id, it is sufficiently unique to query your LDAP source at moment to get any additional information you may want, such as GUID.

Comment: Yes you are correct. but i am also managing the SecurityRole inside my own database. currently inside the securityrole table i am storing two values for each row; securityroleID + UserName (in the following format domainname\username). as i mentioned it is working well in our company. but let say in the future we changed the username, and this user try to access the system and perform some actions ...

Comment: then he will get an error because his new username is no longer inside the security group. but if i store the GUID inside the SecurityRole table , and get the gUID for the login user then i will not have any problem when we chnage the username. now i can retrieve the login user GUID by querying the AD,,, but i am affriad that i will need to query the AD for the GUID wheever the user perform an action ,, what do u think ?

Comment: Why dont you store the AD guid locally and then create a claim and extension method to access that claim?

Comment: what do u mean exactly ? i am using Membership.Providers against our ldap server,, i am not using claims

Comment: Instead of using forms authentication use identity. Then just authenticate a user/pass against LDAP. Now your principal identity object is a claims identity and you can set those to whatever you want.

Comment: @Shoe but the problem is that our active directory is on different domain that the application server. and in this case windows authentication will not work. this is an old problem which i did not find a solution for , taking into consideration the current architecture of our infrastructure. but again although i am using form authentication, but i am authenticating user/password against the LDAP. so users are entering their username/password inside the form , i do not manage the username and password inside my database...

Comment: Okay I see what's happening. You're kind of stuck here and these are the types of things best handled by wif/adfs

Comment: @Shoe waht is wif/adfs ? Anyways returning back to my original question can i get the GUID for my login user?